# Не запускается проект в intellij idea с использованием selenium

Tags: java, intellij-idea, selenium

Пытаюсь запустить следующий код в intellij idea:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

    public class App00 {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            webDriver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    
            System.out.println(webDriver.getTitle());
        }
    }
```

Получаю следующее:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=64598:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\belkina\IdeaProjects\example\target\classes;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium\2.0a1\selenium-2.0a1.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\2.0a1\selenium-chrome-driver-2.0a1.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-common\2.0a1\selenium-common-2.0a1.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-client\2.0a1\selenium-remote-client-2.0a1.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-common\2.0a1\selenium-remote-common-2.0a1.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\commons-httpclient\commons-httpclient\3.1\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-htmlunit-driver\2.0a1\selenium-htmlunit-driver-2.0a1.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\htmlunit\2.6\htmlunit-2.6.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.1\xalan-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\xalan\serializer\2.7.1\serializer-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.4\commons-lang-2.4.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.4\commons-codec-1.4.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\htmlunit-core-js\2.6\htmlunit-core-js-2.6.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\xerces\xercesImpl\2.9.1\xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.3.04\xml-apis-1.3.04.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\nekohtml\nekohtml\1.9.13\nekohtml-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\cssparser\cssparser\0.9.5\cssparser-0.9.5.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\org\w3c\css\sac\1.3\sac-1.3.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\1.4\commons-io-1.4.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\2.0a1\selenium-firefox-driver-2.0a1.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\org\json\json\20080701\json-20080701.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-ie-driver\2.0a1\selenium-ie-driver-2.0a1.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna\3.2.2\jna-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-support\2.0a1\selenium-support-2.0a1.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\com\google\collections\google-collections\1.0-rc3\google-collections-1.0-rc3.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-all\1.1\hamcrest-all-1.1.jar;C:\Users\belkina\.m2\repository\junit\junit\3.8.1\junit-3.8.1.jar App00
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\belkina\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe": CreateProcess error=2, Не удается найти указанный файл
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: chrome
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeBinary.start(ChromeBinary.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.startClient(ChromeDriver.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.init(ChromeDriver.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:48)
    at App00.main(App00.java:6)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\belkina\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe": CreateProcess error=2, Не удается найти указанный файл
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1142)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeBinary.start(ChromeBinary.java:28)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Не удается найти указанный файл
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:483)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:158)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1109)
    ... 6 more
```

Что нужно исправить, чтобы код запустился?

Comment: У вас в логе указано, что не удается найти путь до Chrome, вероятно нужно указать путь вручную через System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver"); Почитать можно здесь, там в начале страницы есть пример под Java: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started

Comment: @Egettl сделал так: 'System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
        WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();' 

но не помогло :с

Answer (score 0):

Разобралась. Стояла какая-то старая версия в зависимости.